# Add css class to child elements based on index in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html

I have an Javascript array of indexes like so [0, 2]

And a bunch of paragraph elements like so

```
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

What would be a succinct way to add a css class to the paragraphs whose index appears in the array? In this case I expect a class to be added to first and third paragraphs.

Output expected:

```
<div>
  <p class=“red”>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p class=“red”>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use `:nth-child()`......

Comment: Might as well post my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/gxnq24fs/

Comment: What @cloned meant is that SO is not a code writing service, we help with written code, and when reading [ask] you'll see it is expected the poster make an effort of their own.

Comment: Edited my fiddle to include element check.

Answer (score 3):

Use `querySelectorAll` and check the index:

```js
const arr = [0, 2];
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.querySelectorAll("p").forEach((elem, idx) => arr.includes(idx) ? elem.classList.add("red") : elem);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

Older browsers:

```js
var arr = [0, 2];
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(function(elem, idx) {
  if (arr.indexOf(idx) > -1) {
    elem.classList.add("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Given that IE is not completely dead, making a note it won't work on it is appropriate (even if it is dead for you, many still need to support it).

Comment: OK @LGSon, I'll add an ES5 version.

Comment: @LGSon we can avoid that `indexOf` or `includes`, please consider the second example in my answer

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I know that, still, your solution might backfire if an index in the array doesn't have an element.

Comment: @JackBashford Well, `forEach` on _nodelist_ won't work either in IE and older browsers

Answer (score 3):

Just a forEach loop is enough.

```js
var arrIndex = [0, 2];
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('div p');

arrIndex.forEach(function(p){
 elems[p] && elems[p].classList.add('red');
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is how to do this: no `NodeList.forEach`, and no index check. Iterating over the array instead of the elements is more efficient by a mile.

Comment: @[LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson) I have edited the answer.

Comment: @ChrisG Since we got this out of the world, I deleted my comments as they have no future value...and will with this too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the paragraph using document.querySelectorAll. Traverse the array and add class to the required paragraph

```js
var a=document.querySelectorAll('p');
var arr=[0,2]
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
if(arr.indexOf(i)>-1)
a[i].classList.add("red");
}
```

```css
.red
{
color:red
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<p>some sample text</p>
<p>some text here</p>
<p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Should be `i == 2` not `3`.

Answer (score 0):

The one way is to select all the elements with that `<p>` element and then check that index of that particular element exist in the array or not:

```js
var arrIndex = [0, 2];
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('div p');
for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
  if(arrIndex.indexOf(i) !== -1){
    elems[i].classList.add('red');
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

> Avoid using `includes()` as it is not supported by IE browser and old JS version browsers

Another way is to just loop the index array to add `red` class:

```js
var arrIndex = [0, 2];
for(var i=0; i<arrIndex.length; i++){
 document.querySelectorAll('div p')[arrIndex[i]].classList.add('red');
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are always siblings then you can use [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Iterate over the array and generate the selector to get elements based on the selector and iterate over the selected elements to add class.

```js
var index = [0, 2];

// generate the selector
var selector = index.map(v => `div p:nth-child(${ v + 1 })`).join();

// get elements using the selector
// iterate and add class
document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(e => e.classList.add('red'))
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <p>some sample text</p>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>some great text</p>
</div>
```

***NOTE :*** It's an ES6 solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some more text</p>
  <p>Some sample text</p>
  <p>Some text here</p>
  <p>Some great text</p>
</div>

.red{
    color: red;
 }


const arr = [0,2]
const para = document.querySelectorAll('p')

arr.forEach(function(arr){
  para[arr].classList.add('red')
})
```

Comment: This is the same as vikasgupta's answer, without the NPE check.